# Java desktop application connecting to web service - oAuth

Tags: java, rest, oauth-2.0, desktop-application

I have no idea how to connect Java desktop application to Shoplo API.
I read many websites but all of them are outdated and its really hard to download binaries they use. I read [www.javacodegeeks.com](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/simple-rest-client-in-java.html) article about "Simple REST client in Java" but it doesn’t cover a oAuth protocol. I don’t know how to send following parameters:

```
oauth_consumer_key - the API KEY for your app
oauth_consumer_secret - the shared secret for your app
```

[Shoplo API](https://docs.shoplo.com/api/auth)

Answer (score 0):

Just follow theese steps - https://docs.shoplo.com/api/auth, use oAuth2 and remember to use theese validation data (you have to create an app on partner accoun to get public and secret key - https://partners.shoplo.com/apps):

```
 $SSOAuthConfig = ['apiBaseUrl'  => 'https://api.shoplo.com',
                   'authBaseUrl' => 'https://auth.shoplo.com',
                   'publicKey'   => getenv('SHOPLO_API_KEY'),
                   'secretKey'   => getenv('SHOPLO_API_SECRET'),
                   'callbackUrl' => getenv('SHOPLO_CALLBACK_URL')]
```

I did this in PHP using their PHP library (https://github.com/Shoplo/sso-auth), but there is a mess between Shoplo docs and library... but it worked at last using config attached above. I know you asked about Java, but it should be helpful while converting to java app.